# Expo EAS build error in EXAppDefinesLoader.m

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo Managed workflow app and when try to build the app with EAS, I get an error:

```
(node_modules/expo/ios/EXAppDefinesLoader.m:13:4)

  11 | {
  12 |   BOOL APP_DEBUG;
> 13 |   [EXAppDefines load:@{
     |    ^ use of undeclared identifier 'EXAppDefines'
  14 | #if DEBUG
  15 |     @"APP_DEBUG": @(YES),
  16 | #else
```

"expo": "~44.0.0",

I have googled that but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to this github post (https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15680) you should delete the react-native-unimodules package from your package.json since is no longer needed in expo sdk 44.0.0

Comment: I upgraded to SK 45 and also deleted react-native-unimodules and the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Any time bro...